# Google Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I wanna use these very simple features in Google Chrome Javascript console but I really cannot find out how (already searched in official documentation,multiple videos and posts...)

1. Writing more than a javascript line! (currently after hitting enter, the previous code executes). Moreover, is there a way to make the 'writing' area of the console larger? (multiple lines)
2. Typical undo and redo edit. Currently control+Z does nothing.

   really weird,

   Thanks in advance,

   Pere

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript console really isn't intended to do serious development in, but it's pretty good.

Shift+enter will let you write multiple lines instead of instantly executing the code.

Comment: I often try out snippets of code in the console and then copy and paste into the program source.  Especially useful when I can't remember the name of an attribute or a method.